# Outlook 2013 invitation replies not automatically tracked

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Does Outlook 2013 **automatically** save/update replies received from invited recipients such as `accepted` / `declined` in tracking status? If so, where? I am the organizer.

I see in tracking status replies are not automatically updated.

I ask because I had 2 persons reply they accepted the invitation but meeting "tracking" continues to show them listed as no response though they have accepted.

- How do I fix this?
- When I receive an accepted/declined reply, do I need to something with it first for it to update with the correct status in the tracking list?
- Is there a setting so I do not have to do this manually?

It would help to keep an accurate track of RVSPs as they arrive.

Comment: Seriously, I had know idea how formatting affected my question so seriously, so I again, apologize. Really.  I am an old-school DOS-taught secretary who is only asking for some advice. Did not mean to sound off any shouting alarms. If you have an answer for my query it would be seriously appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Please take a look, HTH: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2215547/en-us

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks very much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook will only track replies to your default (personal) calendar, so if you are using a shared event booking calendar it will not track them (although you should still receive an email when someone accepts/declines the event.

If you really need to track responses you need a dedicated Active Directory account, and you can add a second profile in your outlook to view it's calendar.